# Thread not finishing (even though I'm calling pthread_join)

Tags: c, multithreading

So strange issue. I spawn my threads here. This should just keep looping until I kill it.

```
void accept_connections(int sock_fd)
{
    while(1)
    {
            /*Whole bunch of irrelevant stuff*/
        pthread_create(&(new_connect->thread), NULL, &thread_dispatch, new_connect);
        printf("Thread spawned.\n");
        pthread_join(new_connect->thread, NULL);
            /*Exit when catches a sigint */
    }
}
```

And the function the pthreads run:

```
void* thread_dispatch(void* new_connect)
{

    printf("Thread working.\n");

    http_t *http = malloc(sizeof(http_t));

    int bytes_read = http_read(http, fd);

    printf("read %d\n",bytes_read); //this prints
    printf("status %s\n",http->status); //this prints
    printf("body %s\n",http->body); //this prints
    const char* get_status = http_get_status(http);
    char* filename = process_http_header_request(get_status);
    printf("filename: %s", filename); //this doesn't print unless I do exit(1) on next line
    return NULL;
}
```

1. why doesn't the last statement get printed? I'm calling pthread_join which should wait for the thread to return, and then terminate, right?
2. Are my threads being terminated correctly this way?

Comment: A `thread` should exit and not `return` value. Please change your `return NULL` to `pthread_exit()` and your code should work fine.

Comment: @Ganesh Calling return is perfectly valid. `return foo;` is equivalent to `pthread_exit(foo);` _unless_ the thread in question is the main thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your last line isn't printing because `stdout` is line buffered and you don't have a newline (`\n`) in that last `printf()`. `exit()` is likely flushing the `stdout` buffer.

Comment: Although I'm guessing you probably want a newline in that `printf()` anyway, I would also put a `fflush(stdout);` between the `printf()` and `return` in order to be certain it flushes the buffer. stdout gets flushed every time there is a newline by convention, but I'm not sure there's any standard that requires it. In other words, I think it would be legitimate for an OS _not_ to flush the buffer when there is a newline; it just happens that the ones people use most do.